# To join 2 tables with specific columns and to create new column

Tags: join

I have created 2 tables in mysql
Table1 (sno, name, student id)
Table2 (sub id, sub code)

I need the another table as
Table3 (sub id, student id, mark)

How to join table1 and table2 to get the columns sub id and student id and to create new column mark to the table (table3).

I have created table 1 and 2 . Struggling to create table 3 .

Comment: You create table 3 the same way you created tables 1 and 2. Are you asking how to create a table?

Comment: Thanks for replying..No. I need to get 2 columns from 2 different tables. And to add new column to the newly created table.

Comment: Your question is not clear. Please give an example of what you want to do. Try to separate creating tables and creating columns from querying data - usually, those are two separate activities that are not done at the same time.